# Js ‘import’ Statement invalid Webview android version 8 and lower

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin, webview

I am implementing a webview to load a remote blazor webassembly page url as part of a Xamarin android app. The page to load has Js scripts that include ‘import’ statements. This works fine on Android 10 and up but keeps giving “invalid token ‘import’” on lower versions. I found out that js ‘import’ is not supported on the webview of android versions lower than 8-9. Is there any workaround or an alternative webview implementation.

Thank You

I came across Crosswalk but its an obsolete webview alternative, Geckoview as well seems obsolete and the repo is not recommending it for production

Comment: Did you try this patch? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-calltarget-task-returned-false-but-did-not-log/955972

Comment: @jdweng that is xml related. This is Javascript chromium problem. 

Thank You

Comment: Still you should make sure all patches are installed.

Comment: All patches are installed. Its a problem of the Webview engine of android 8 and down not supporting javascript "import" statements i guess. So i am thinking of getting an alternative view engine besides the native android webview.

Comment: The parsing of the js is failing.  You do not need to view the js, just parse.  Maybe use Powershell method on android.  See : https://dev.to/thementor/i-run-powershell-on-android-and-so-can-you-458k  Use ConvertFrom-JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by switching to MAUI and running the whole blazor itself in the app.